# Finder tag pollution avoidance: view subsets of tags, not a global list of tags

Tags: finder-tag

I'll start this question with example of the problem I'd like to solve.

I like to tag my apps by category: productivity, development, media, etc.  I like to tag my movies by genre: action, drama, porn, comedy, etc.
I like to tag my personal documents by some other criteria: bills, medical, auto-related, etc.

All these tags end up in a big messy list.  So when I go to tag another app, I have to scan this list of items irrelevant to current context.  Applying "comedy" to apps is invalid action and, in perfect universe, would not be available.

Is there a way to somehow define contexts where certain tags become available while the rest of them disappear?  Is there a way to organize the tags other than them all being in on big stupid system-wide global list?

Comment: To follow up, it seems that Ironic's Leap product addresses this.  It displays only tags present in current directory and its children.  I was too confused by the rest of Leap's UI to actually propose it as the answer to the question.  What a mess that UI.

Comment: I agree that [Leap](http://www.ironicsoftware.com/leap/) by Ironic Software is a good solution.